# How to split a Python string with numbers and letters?

Tags: python, string, split

I have strings that have optional numbers and letters, such as '01a', 'b' and '02'. These strings have always two parts, numbers on the left, and letters on the right side. I'd like to split these strings to get the numbers and letters separately. How can I define `mySplit` in a way to get this result?

```
>>> map(mySplit, ['01123absd', 'bsdf', '02454'])

[('01123', 'absd'), (None, 'bsdf'), ('02454', None)]
```

Comment: Will it always be formatted numbers then letters?

Comment: Will there always be only two parts?

Comment: Yes, there will be always two parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this. What we want is:

- a string that starts with 0 or more digits,
- a string that ends with 0 or more letters.

Note that the `regex` will create named groups, it is also compiled *once* to be more efficient *every time* is it called.

```
import re
regex = re.compile("^(?P<numbers>\d*)(?P<letters>\w*)$")

def myFunction(entry):
  (numbers, letters) = regex.search(entry).groups()
  return (numbers or None, letters or None)

map(myFunction, ['01123absd', 'bsdf', '02454'])
```

The call on the last line gives the following output:

```
[('01123', 'absd'), (None, 'bsdf'), ('02454', None)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to [jramirez answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21918162/1639625), just a bit shorter:

```
def myFunction(s):
    return (''.join(c for c in s if c.isdigit()) or None, 
            ''.join(c for c in s if c.isalpha()) or None)
```

A little shorter still using `filter`:

```
def myFunction(s):
    return (''.join(filter(str.isdigit, s)) or None, 
            ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, s)) or None)
```

Output:

```
print(*map(myFunction, ['01123absd', 'bsdf', '02454', '012abc345def']))
('01123', 'absd') (None, 'bsdf') ('02454', None) ('012345', 'abcdef')
```

Comment: Great solution as it's much faster than using regexp.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions here:

```
import re

def myFunction(numbers_and_letters):
    m = re.match(r"([a-z]*)([0-9]*)", numbers_and_letters)
    return tuple(v == "" and None or v for v in m.groups())
```

Comment: should it not use stars since neither sort is necessary?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I need to change the ''s to None also.

Comment: `return tuple(v == "" and None or v for v in m.groups())`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use regex this is a solution:

```
def split_num_str(my_str):
    num = [x for x in my_str if x.isdigit()]
    num = "".join(num)

    if not num:
        num = None

    my_str = [x for x in my_str if x.isalpha()]
    my_str = ''.join(my_str)

    if not my_str:
        my_str = None

    return num, my_str

m = map(split_num_str, ['01123absd', 'bsdf', '02454'])
print m
```

result = `[('01123', 'absd'), (None, 'bsdf'), ('02454', None)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re


def myFunction(t):
    m = re.match(r"([a-z]*)([0-9]*)", t)
    x,y = m.groups()
    if x=='': x= None    
    if y=='': y= None    
    return ((x,y))

for s in ['01123absd', 'bsdf', '02454']:
    print myFunction(s)
```

produces:

```
(None, '01123')
('bsdf', None)
(None, '02454')
```